# Multiprocessing HDF5 file read, what is better, multiple connections or repeated spawning

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multiprocessing, hdf5

I am trying to process data in parallel. I have an HDF5 file where the data is stored, a table for each sensor. Data for a sensor is independent of the other sensors. My HDF5 file is structured like so:

```
/root
    /sens_metadata
    /sens1
    /sens2
    ...
```

Each sensor table contains a `datetime[64]` index, 3 columns of data, and 2 columns of scores denoting confidence in the data. My question is which of the following is the better way to program:

## Option 1

Open a connection to the HDF5 file for each child process

```
def parfunc(sens_id):
    with pd.HDFStore('data.h5', 'r') as store:
        try:
            df = store[sens_id]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        else:
            # Do work on the df

def main():
    import multiprocessing as mp
    maxproc = mp.cpu_count()
    with pd.HDFStore('data.h5', 'r') as store:
        sens_list = store['sens_metadata'].index.tolist()
    with mp.Pool(maxproc, maxtaskperchild=100) as p:
        ret = p.map(parfunc, sens_list)
```

## Option 2

Read sensors in the main thread, reinitialize Pool at each iteration

```
def parfunc(df):
    # Do work on the df

def main():
    import multiprocessing as mp
    maxproc = mp.cpu_count()
    i = 0
    df_list, ret = [], []
    with pd.HDFStore('data.h5', 'r') as store:
        sens_list = store['sens_metadata'].index.tolist()
        for sens in sens_list:
            try:
                df_list.extend([store[sens]])
            except KeyError:
                pass
            else:
                if i == maxproc:
                    with mp.Pool(maxproc) as p:
                        ret.extend(p.map(parfunc, df_list))
                    i, df_list = 0, []
                i += 1
```

It takes about 0.25 seconds to fetch the data for a table now. However, that table size will only grow, taking longer and longer to get the data. On a single process, processing a table of data takes roughly 1 minute.

Which of the above options is the better way to do this? Or is there another way that is even better?

---

## Option Not Possible:

Passing the HDF5 buffer object is not possible because it cannot be pickled. (The object is a child of `WeakValueDictionary`.)

```
from functools import partial

def parfunc(hdf_buff, sens_id):
    try:
        df = hdf_buff[sens_id]
    except KeyError:
        pass
    else:
        # Do work on the df

def main():
    import multiprocessing as mp
    maxproc = mp.cpu_count()
    with pd.HDFStore('data.h5', 'r') as store:
        sens_list = store['sens_metadata'].index.tolist()
        with mp.Pool(maxproc, maxtaskperchild=100) as p:
            ret = pd.concat(p.map(partial(parfunc, hdf_buff=store), sens_list))
```

Comment: It depends on the numbers of indexes, files, gigabytes, etc.  Since you already wrote the code both ways, you are in the best position to determine which is faster--just test them both!  But if I had to decide without any empirical data, I would prefer the one where you load all the data in a single process and then do the calculations in parallel.

Comment: @JohnZwinck, I ended up choosing the first option, where the data is loaded and processed in its own subprocess. The other one was getting too hairy, especially maintaining references so that data got properly sliced based on intermediate results. Loading each sensor data into a process, and keeping it there made the code and logic much simpler, straightforward and neat. I also think I avoided a lot of overhead in terms of spawning processes, and then communicating between them. I haven't done a time test, never managed to finish the second option.

Comment: Check the status of [this ticket](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12236) before trying a modification of the "Option not possible". Even using `initalizer` and `initargs` to circumvent the pickling issue, the multiple requests from the same connection hurdle will thwart progress.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little bit old but it can help if someone is dealing with some related problem. I was reading about your not possible option because I had the same problem and after reading this [link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12236). I implemented something like this

```
HDF_LOCK = threading.Lock()
HDF_PATH = 'path'

@contextmanager
def locked_file():
  with HDF_LOCK:
    with h5py.File(HDF_PATH, 'r') as file:
        yield file

def process_files():
    with locked_file() as file:
        timestamp = file.attrs.get('start_timestamp', 0)
        dataset = file.get('series')

        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(10) as executor:
            for group, res in ((group, executor.submit(process_groups, group,
                 timestamp)) for group in dataset):
                print(res.result())
```

process_groups is my function where I'm dealing with the HDF5 file. You can use the locked_file() function inside your main function to process the file.